# Prove that $w(x) = (x+31)(x+29)(x-10)(x^{2}-2019)$ is divisible by 30.

Tags: polynomials

> Prove that for any $x \in \mathbb Z$ we have that $$w(x) =
>  (x+31)(x+29)(x-10)(x^{2}-2019)$$ is divisible by 30.

I am not sure how to prove this. 
Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Prove that it‘s divisible by $2$, $3$ and $5$.

Comment: Show that the expression is divisible by $2$ , $3$ and $5$ for every integer $x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we show that $w(x)$ is a multiple of $2$.

- If $x$ is even, then $x-10$ is even.
- If $x$ is odd, then $x + 31$ is even.

Next, we show that $w(x)$ is a multiple of $3$.

- If $x$ is a multiple of $3$, then $x^2 - 2019$ is a multiple of $3$.
- If $x$ has remainder $1$ after division by $3$, then $x + 29$ is a
  multiple of $3$.
- If $x$ has remainder $2$ after division by $3$, then $x + 31$ is a multiple of $3$.

Finally, we show that $w(x)$ is a multiple of $5$.

- If $x$ is a multiple of $5$, then $x-10$ is also a multiple of $5$.
- If $x$ has remainder $1$ after division by $5$, then $x + 29$ is a
  multiple of $5$.
- If $x$ has remainder $2$ after division by $5$, then $x^2 - 2019$ is
  a multiple of $5$.
- If $x$ has remainder $3$ after division by $5$, then $x^2 - 2019$ is
  a multiple of $5$.
- If $x$ has remainder $4$ after division by $5$, then $x+31$ is a multiple of $5$.

Thus, for any $x \in \mathbb Z$ we have that $w(x) $ is divisible by $2, 3, $ and $5$. Thus, $w(x)$ is divisible by $30$.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce it first:
$$w(x) =  (x+31)(x+29)(x-10)(x^{2}-2019)=\\
(x+1+30)(x-1+30)(x-10)(x^{2}-9-67\cdot 30)=\\
30A+(x-10)(x-3)(x-1)(x+1)(x+3).$$
Can you take it from here?